# Using reindex with value_counts in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I'd like to use value_counts with groupby, and keep all labels in the original dataframe. In the example below for, instance,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'month': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
        'day': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1],
        'value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 1, 1],
    }
)
df.groupby(['month', 'day'])['value'].value_counts(normalize=True)

month  day  value
1      1    1        0.333333
            2        0.333333
            3        0.333333
       2    4        0.333333
            5        0.333333
            6        0.333333
2      1    1        1.000000
```

I'd like to show all values from 1 to 6 for all combinations of month and day (those that do not show up would have a value of zero.

Adding `.reindex(range(1, 6))`, produces the error:

> ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got
> 'long'

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
(df.groupby(['month', 'day'])['value']
 .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(normalize=True)
        .reindex(range(1, 7), fill_value=0)
        .rename_axis('value'))
 .rename('proportion'))
```

Output:

```
month  day  value
1      1    1        0.333333
            2        0.333333
            3        0.333333
            4        0.000000
            5        0.000000
            6        0.000000
       2    1        0.000000
            2        0.000000
            3        0.000000
            4        0.333333
            5        0.333333
            6        0.333333
2      1    1        1.000000
            2        0.000000
            3        0.000000
            4        0.000000
            5        0.000000
            6        0.000000
Name: proportion, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your value column to `category` (optionally specifying all existing categories with `categories=[…]`, then `value_counts` will automatically compute all categories:

```
df['value'] = pd.Categorical(df['value'])

df.groupby(['month', 'day'])['value'].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

Output:

```
month  day  value
1      1    2        0.333333
            1        0.333333
            3        0.333333
            4        0.000000
            5        0.000000
            6        0.000000
       2    4        0.333333
            6        0.333333
            5        0.333333
            1        0.000000
            2        0.000000
            3        0.000000
2      1    1        1.000000
            5        0.000000
            6        0.000000
            4        0.000000
            3        0.000000
            2        0.000000
       2    5        0.000000
            4        0.000000
            3        0.000000
            2        0.000000
            1        0.000000
            6        0.000000
Name: proportion, dtype: float64
```

Comment: the code should only add missing values under the value column, so month and day should be as in the ouput above

Comment: @zzzbbx I see, it would be best to edit the question with the exact expected output for clarity. That said, it's the same logic, then use a categorical on value (see update)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pivot table to do this because your dataframe has multi index due to group by statement. Something like below -

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'month': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
        'day': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1],
        'value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 1, 1],
    }
)

pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['month', 'day'], columns=['value'], aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
pivot = pivot.div(pivot.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
print(pivot)
```

Output :

```
value             1         2         3         4         5         6
month day                                                            
1     1    0.333333  0.333333  0.333333  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
      2    0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.333333  0.333333  0.333333
2     1    1.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
```